# Is it a bad idea to make message class for communication between two objects?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Upon a existing source code framework, I'm trying to make source code to communicate between two objects (e.g., A and B).

AFAIK, it is impossible to deliver the message by using queue in each object due to incomplete type inference.

For example (assuming each class is defined in different header file, A.h B.h),

In class A:

```
B* b; // assume we have this declaration in class A
b->receiveMessageFromA(data); // object 'b' wants to receive a message from object 'a'
```

In class B:

```
A* a; // assume we have this declaration in class B
a->receiveMessageFromB(data); // object 'a' wants to receive a message from object 'b'
```

Above implementation cannot be done even if I use forward class declaration since incomplete type compile error occurs.

To compensate this, I thought that defining class called `MessageQueue` can help this.

Now, I want to give simple example to define class A, B, and Message Queue.

```
class Message { // Assume Request is defined somewhere
public: 
  std::vector<Request> messageFromA; // message q
  std::vector<Request> messageFromB; // message q
}

class A {
public:
  Message* msg;

  void sendMsgToB(Request req) {
    msg->messageFromA.push_back(req); // send message to B
  }
  void tick() {
    if (msg->messageFromB().size() != 0) {
      // if 'messageFromB' queue has elements, A can receive message from B
    }
  }
}
class B {
public:
  Message* msg;
  void sendMsgToA(Request req) {
    msg->messageFromB.push_back(req);
  }
  void tick() {
    if (msg->messageFromA.size() != 0) {
      // if 'messageFromA' queue has elements, B can receive message from A
    }
  }
}
```

Is designing `class Message` is a bad choice to communicate between two classes?

I heard that there exists listener/observer pattern, but it might require modifying a lot of source code in the existing framework by polluting original design patterns.

Comment: The general structure I've seen for messages is a struct of data fields, call it `Message`.. Each class can take a `std::queue<Message>&` when constructed. Create the `std::queue<Message>` before `A` and `B` are created, then pass your `queue` to each class constructor. If this is single threaded, you're done. If it's multi-threaded, make sure to include a `mutex`. If the classes need to communicate across machines or time or both, serialize your data before sending it.

Comment: Consider using an existing implementation:
https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/MPMCQueue.h
https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/ProducerConsumerQueue.h

Answer (score 1):

> Above implementation cannot be done even if I use forward class declaration since incomplete type compile error occurs.

Sure it can be done. You can use the following order:

1. Declare A and B (in any order)
2. Define A and B (in any order) - they should only rely on the declaration of one another such as `A*` or `B*` member. Be sure to not define any member function that relies on the definition of the other class.
3. Only now that both classes have been defined, define the (member) functions that depend on definitions of A and / or B (in any order) - which may involve things such as `a->receiveMessageFromB(data);` and `b->receiveMessageFromA(data);`

A minimal example:

```
// 1. declare the classes
struct A;
struct B;

// 2. define the classes
struct A {
    B* b;
    void receiveMessageFromB(int);
};
struct B {
    A* a;
    void receiveMessageFromA(int);
};

// 3. define the functions that rely on the class definitions
void A::receiveMessageFromB(int data) {
    if (data % 2)
        b->receiveMessageFromA(data - 1);
}
void B::receiveMessageFromA(int data) {
    if (data % 2)
        a->receiveMessageFromB(data + 1);
}
```

Comment: calling `a->receiveMessageFromB(data)` inside `class B` shows me incomplete type error

Comment: @sungjuncho `a->receiveMessageFromB(data)` statement is an expression. It is something that you have to write within a function definition. Define that function after defining `A`, and then you won't be shown incomplete type error.

Comment: In my framework, class A and class B are defined as template class and all function definition is defined in header file. To do this, I think I need to separate definition and declaration. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @sungjuncho Yes, you have to separate the definition and declaration of the member functions. I wrote an example for you.

Comment: Thanks for your concrete example. By the way, designing class like this is bad idea? or how about defining `class Message` as I mentioned?

Comment: @sungjuncho There's nothing inherently bad about message queues. What *is* dubious about these examples are the  bare pointers: How do you guarantee the lifetime of the pointed object is longer than the lifetime of the pointer?

Comment: is the message queues you are indicating `class Message` or my original idea? The life time of each pointed object finishes when the program finishes. Additionally, is it possible to do dynamic_cast only with class declaration?

Comment: @sungjuncho Not possible. You need definition.